# Errors using Custom Point Annotation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkpointannotation

I am using a custom point annotation that includes an image. I am getting several errors such as "Computed property must have an explicit type" and "Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value" with the var annotation line. If I fix one another pops up.  Does anyone know how to achieve this in Swift 3?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        let eventPageViewController:EventPageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventPage") as! EventPageViewController

        var annotation = view.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation{
            eventPageViewController.photo = annotation?.imageName
        }

        self.present(eventPageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is the Custom Point Class:

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: UIImage!
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `var annotation =` was meant to be `if let annotation =`?

Comment: it was originally but that brought errors too @dan

Comment: what is your goal ?

Comment: please take a look here @Bucket

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046901/sending-images-to-several-instances-of-a-viewcontroller-in-swift @Bucket

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
let annotation1 = view.annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
eventPageViewController.photo = annotation1.imageName
```